# Stripe Connect Authentication failure - invalid_client: No such API key: Bearer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, stripe-connect

I'm working on Ruby on Rails with the [OmniAuth-StripeConnect Gem](https://github.com/isaacsanders/omniauth-stripe-connect), and every time I try to connect to the Stripe Connect API I get this failure in authentication, 'redirecting' me to the failure method of the Omniauth callback controller :

```
E, [2018-05-28T13:41:50.435158 #58778] ERROR -- omniauth (stripe_connect) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_client: No such API key: Bearer
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "No such API key: Bearer"
}
```

I found in the doc that an error of `invalid_client` meant either one of these :
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#post-deauthorize-error-codes

- `client_id` does not belong to you
- `stripe_user_id` does not exist or is not connect to your application
- API key mode (live or test mode) does not match the `client_id` mode

But i doubled checked and it's none of these.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, I know but I came across this error today, too and it may help others in future. The owner of the repo/gem said that he wasn't "really supporting" it anymore, anyway. This answer assumes you're trying to get a user to create their account on Stripe and pass an auth token back to your controller.

I decided to skip using the gem altogether. After 'undoing' the installation instructions, I found that keeping the `stripe_connect` method under the `OmniauthCallbacksController` still worked as you'd expect - you just don't get the error described as above.

According to the Stripe Connect docs (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#redirected), if you don't receive an error code, then the request was successful. You should receive an authorization code inside the response which can be used to access that user's Stripe account via their API. You'll only have five minutes to use that token before it expires. I imagine you'll need to start the whole process over again if you miss it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean that you skipped the gem all together?  Did you write your own omniauth strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are testing with live card with test API Keys?

Answer (score 0):

For others who may find this, when I was facing this issue, it was because I did not properly set up the omniauth initializer to include the required stripe keys:

I had set up this file:

```
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :stripe_connect, ENV['STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['STRIPE_CLIENT_SECRET']
end
```

But forgot to put the keys into my `.env` file.

Make sure you set up your environment with the proper keys.